# Best way to calculated how many times a value appears in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I wish to calculate how many times each number appears in the array.

The numbers are all between 1 - 10

So for example:
{1,2,2,5,5,6,7,8,2)
Would return 3 instances for '2'. And 2 instances for '5' and 1 instance for the rest.

What is the best way to do this, other then me creating 10 for loops?

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 5):

[`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
print_r(
    array_count_values($array)
);
```